# Between two(2) Dates with date format for column (Y-m-d)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I have this code as post request that collects the `$start_date` & `$end_date`

```
$start_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($request->start_date));


$end_date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($request->end_date));
```

and I have this query to get all the records between two(2) dates

```
$date_time_records = DateTimeAPI::select('ACNo','datetime','state','deviceID','status')
        ->whereBetween('datetime', [$start_date, $end_date])
        ->get();
```

But the problem is:

The field format of `datetime` in mysql is `(Y-m-d h:i:s)`

What I'm trying to do is to match the date range and the field `datetime` with the same format.

Like this `('Y-m-d')`

The select query works fine if the `start_date` and `end_date` formatted as `(Y-m-d h:i:s)`. But What I only need is `(Y-m-d)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with php but can't you just use `date("Y-m-d 0:0:0",`...?

Comment: The start_date and end_date only have Y-m-d data. Like start_date = "2019-04-05" and end_date =2019-04-05" and the datetime field in my db contains the record of datetime = "2019-04-05 8:28:00"

Comment: Laravel store date as `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` format to get second based result. You can use as in below answer. And also if you want to get data between current dates from morning to night you must edit your date as `$start_date = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime($request->start_date));` and `$end_date = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59",strtotime($request->end_date));`

Comment: what I only wanted not to included hours to be filtered that's why start_date contains only the data with this kind of format (Y-m-d)

Answer (score 2):

change your code

```php
$start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($request->start_date));
$end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($request->end_date));
```

or using carbon

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;
Carbon::parse($start_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
Carbon::parse($end_date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

## Laravel 5

Use `->whereDateBetween()` instead on `->whereBetween()`

`->whereDateBetween('datetime', [$start_date, $end_date])`

Answer (score 2):

**You can also use**

```
$query->whereDate('datetime', '>=', $start_date)->whereDate('datetime', '<=', $end_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned that

```
your mysql column is of format - Y-m-d h:i:s
and format in date range variable is - Y-m-d.
```

So, you can use `DATE()` function of MYSQL and implement in you query as below

```
$date_time_records = DateTimeAPI::select('ACNo','datetime','state','deviceID','status')
    ->whereBetween('DATE(datetime)', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->get();
```